# Access Violation when using glGenFrameBuffers SFML + GLEW

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, glew

I creating a small renderer using OpenGL and am getting the access violation error only when using that particular function. Other Gl functions work perfectly fine.

What I have tried so far

- setting `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE` before glewInit
- using `glGenFramebuffersEXT` instead of `glGenFramebuffers` - Same error

Here is the code I am using to initialize SFMLand GLEW

```
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 24;
settings.stencilBits = 8;
settings.majorVersion = 3;
settings.minorVersion = 3;
settings.attributeFlags = sf::ContextSettings::Core;

window = new sf::Window( sf::VideoMode( screenWidth, screenHeight, 32 ), "OpenGL SFML", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close, settings );

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

if ( GLEW_OK != glewInit( ) )
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

System information:

- OS: Windows 10
- GPU : GTX 1060
- GLEW version: 2.1.0

Comment: What are you getting for `GL_VERSION` after that `glewInit()`?

Comment: I am getting 4.4.0 NVIDIA 441.08

Comment: Possible duplicate of [glGenFramebuffers() access violation when using GLFW + GLEW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165863/glgenframebuffers-access-violation-when-using-glfw-glew)

Comment: Run glewinfo.exe in the glew library directory. It will tell you which extensions are enabled, and thus, if glGenFrameBuffers is available to you.